# When OAuth user takes over the authorisation code

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, csrf

So there's this question bothering me a while already. Consider this scenario:

Background:

- Application is a SPA which communicates with a server (API)
- Application server (API) is stateless. It doesn't store any user session, just authenticates the user with a JWT token
- Application server has a `/login` endpoint which redirect to an authorization url
- Authorization url is decorated with a `state` parameter which is being generated in the `/login` endpoint
- Invoking the `/login` endpoint returns a `Set-Cookie` header with the `state` value (sets the cookie on the invokers' browser)
- Let's say that the `state` value is just a `userId`

Scenario:

1. There's an user Tony in the application
2. Tony goes to `/login` url which redirects him to an authorisation url
3. Tony enters his credentials but somehow stops the redirect flow and gets the authorisation `code`, the `redirect_url` and the `state` query param with user id
4. Tony finds out that after successful login the server does some actions on his account (dunno, just some stuff)

Now the question is: What stops Tony to use this data to send a request to `/callback` endpoint (url from `redirect_url`) but changing the user id from the `state` param to some other user id and do something on his behalf?

The only thing that comes to my mind is... How will Tony know the id of another user. But if it's publicly available - then what should I do in this example to prevent this kind of situation?

I hope that my example is clear enough. If not - please ask, I'll explain what's going on in my mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state parameter is set by the App before sending Tony on to the authorisation server via a http redirect. It passes the state param value to the authorisation server via the URL e.g. `authserver/authorize?state=tony...` The app may create a browser cookie to bind the state value to Tony's browser or hold it in some other way in session.

Now when Tony's intercepted and modified callback URL is posted to the App e.g. `app/callback?code=abcd&state=bob...`  the request may be coming from Tony's browser, or some other browser completely, but either way the app will not be able to match `bob` within the browser session, as the app did not set and store a state of `bob` in this session.

Even if Tony leaves the state as `tony` but calls the callback from a different browser session the app is not going to be able to match it so will not return a token.

Also note that the `code` can only be used once.

Also if you have control as to what `state` the Application server sets you could hash the user id and use the base64ed hash as a `state` parameter. That way you can't really guess another valid state.

Comment: That's a really nice explanation! I understand that now. But! I still have some questions. What if:

1. The app is stateless (doesn't couple users browser session with the server)
2. The `state` is passed into Tony's browser as a cookie

And in this situation: can't just Tony - while in the browser when he sees the `code` and `redirect_url` in the browser URL - change the `state` param to i.e. `state=bob` and then set the cookie in the browser to the same value?

Comment: If the app is stateless then does it generate some sort of user-based hash value to verify `state` parameters? You may need to flesh out the scenario with a few more specifics. Is the app native / SPA / server app? Where is the app running? How is `state` being generated? What passes the `state` into the browser as a cookie and what sets the cookie?

Comment: I've added some background in the main question to make it more clear. Please tell if you need to know anything else to understand the case more clearly.

Comment: So in Oauth2 terminology, Tony (`resource owner`) uses your SPA (`client`) which in turn requires access to an API server (`resource server`) which authorises the SPA (`client`) if it presents a valid JWT bearer token.  Your example seems to imply the API server is both the `client` and `resource server` whereas the SPA should be the `client` and should manage state.

Comment: Yes, the API server is both the `client`, because he's talking with Google API and a `resource server`, because it stores i.e. users aggregated Google API Data. User has his own account in the API server, and the account can be linked to multiple Google Accounts. Is something wrong in this approach?

Comment: No that's okay. I can imagine a scenario where Tony logs into/authenticates with the App as Tony but in the app he may log into 3 different google accounts which will associate him with those accounts. Then if he calls "getmygoogledata" in the API app, the API app can then make calls to google API for the 3 associated accounts and return one set of data. Not sure I totally get your usage scenario but AFAIK the App/API server which creates the state is setting a cookie between itself and the browser  - how would you make this app set a cookie for `bob`?

Comment: You get it totally right! The scenario which I'm concerned about is when Tony stops the redirect flow and in this particular moment (while having cookies himself) he could change the `state` param and then change the cookie in his browser via JavaScript (changing i.e. to `bob`) and sends the request. I can't validate if its really Tony or someone else sending the request on the server side. I can only validate if the `state` query param matches the cookie from his browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166404/discussion-between-sarneeh-and-iandayman).